# Can a local Linux user map via authentication to an Active Directory user?

Tags: linux, centos, samba, active-directory

Via Samba I have joined a CentOS workstation to an Active Directory domain.  I can log in as an Active Directory user on the CentOS workstation.  So far, so good.

What I would like to do however is run a process on the CentOS workstation as a specific, non-root user, and for that user to authenticate to Active Directory in order to access files in a share.

Let's say for example, a daemon process is started via an init script or systemd.  That daemon process, owned by user 'joe', would authenticate to Active Directory as joseph@EXAMPLEDOMAIN.COM.  And, then the process would connect to a Windows share to copy files.

Googling for how to do something like this is challenging as most references talk about how to authenticate an Active Directory user on a Linux workstation.

I suspect there's going to be some Kerberos 'magic' involved but I haven't gotten anything to work yet.

Comment: You say you “haven’t gotten anything to work yet.”  Have you tried anything?  Please describe what you’ve tried, so people won’t waste their time suggesting solutions that you’ve already eliminated.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

There's much less magic than on Windows – the Kerberos tickets you have are actually completely unrelated to your system account.

This means you can just run `kinit joseph@EXAMPLEDOMAIN.COM`, enter your AD credentials, and be "logged in" as far as `smbclient` and other Kerberos-aware programs are concerned.

(For non-interactive operation you might use [kstart](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/) to properly automate this.)